# How to speed up the screenshot in c#

Tags: c#, performance, screenshot

Basically i'm trying to make the screenshot function faster, because it only gives me around 230 iterations/s, but i have to make it faster than 1ms (over a 1000 iterations a second), is there a way i can do that? Here is my code:

```
public static Bitmap TakeScreenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h)
        {
            var bounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(x, y), new System.Drawing.Size(w, h));

            var img = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(new System.Drawing.Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), System.Drawing.Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }

            return img;
        }
```

I expected a better perfomarmance from c#

Comment: You may get better performance by directly accessing the frame buffer. This will differ on each system, but technically it should be possible to directly access the memory where the currently displayed "image" is stored.

Comment: 1000 frames a second? why? nothing on the screen will move that fast to make this necessary.

Comment: You only can see about 60 frames a second.  So I would sample 120 frames a second.

Comment: Aside from the previous points about the redundancy of this you might be able to speed it up some by reusing the bitmap and the graphic object across calls.

Comment: I tried all of the methods, but none of them worked for me

Comment: @Xinon Please explain why you need such a high frame rate. Typically, Monitors have a frame rate of 60-70Hz, so your graphics card will typically not even cope with that, and even fast games don't go much above that.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive